# Need advice on how to go about creating a very specific custom menu

Tags: routes

I have the need to create a custom menu that is giving me quite the challenge. I have a site that focuses around properties as the main content type. Several other content types have references to the property, such as creating journal entries or activities.

Several paths were defined via a hook_menu instance where each path was a MENU_LOCAL_TASK. Others, such as journals (which is its own content type) were just done using the standard drupal form so they didn't require an entry in hook_menu.

I am in the process of trying to create a property menu that will cover any and all things that one can do for a property. I want to create a menu of all the links that are applicable for a property, even if the content is of another content type with a reference to a property. Initially, I thought a block would do just fine and I could create custom markup that would mimic a menu. However, several of the links would need access to the $node object that represents the property, and hook_block_view doesn't seem to have a way to pass parameters as you can with hook_menu.

Hook_menu doesn't work for all my links either cause some of them aren't part of the actual property content type. I realize this is confusing and I apologize for that, but if anybody has faced a similar type of problem and can offer some suggestions, I would appreciate that. To complicate matters even more, one user can have more than one property, causing all of the links in this menu to change for each property they have.

An example menu and paths might be something like this

Overview - node/[property-nid]/overview (custom page - hook_menu local task)
map boundaries - node/[property-nid]/map/edit-property (custom page - hook_menu local task)
Map features - node/[property-nid]/features/manage (custom page - hook_menu local task)
Journals - forest-journals/[property-nid] (a view)
Activities - activities/[property-nid] (a view)
Foresters - foresters-near-me (a view)

Comment: can you format your text a bit, so it is easier to read? like, with separate sections/paragraphs? And add an example?

Comment: If you want this block to be displayed on a page that is displaying a single node, the entire `$node` object is available via `$node=menu_get_object();` which you can call from inside your `hook_block_view()`.  It's cached so this also won't be a performance hit, eg, it's not reloading the whole node object from the db.

Comment: @donquixote - i tried to add some formatting and an example

Comment: @Jimajamma - It will be all over the place, not just on single node pages, though some will be single node pages

Comment: Does every url in the menu contain the [property-nid] ?

Comment: And could you change forest-journals/[property-nid] to node/[property-nid]/forest-journals?

Comment: Nope, they don't all contain the property nodeID. I will want this menu on the pages that show the individual activity nodes or journal nodes which only have a reference to the property they belong to. I could probably change the view for forest-journals but i don't see how that helps me any.